# How can I create dynamic reference in c# project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, system.reflection

I have 2 dlls with the same API(including namespaces) and same name. But one of this only for one type of systems(for example xp), and second for another(for example vista+). They have another path (for example, `\xp\example.dll` and `\vista\example.dll`). How can i set condition for this in project xaml file? If this is imposible, what things i need to use? I look to the side of System.Reflection, but my approach(using `Assemblies`) is n't suitable because i'm using lots of types and methods from library in dll file. Please tell me decision or direction to solving a problem.

Comment: I think that you can include the dll in your project, then when you install it it will copy that dll to your instalation directory, so it will always be in the same location

Comment: Maybe have a look at MEF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What is different between these? Is it not something you can determine during runtime which methods are available by determining what system its running on?

Comment: @bto.rdz i cant do this because that is very big project, and my task is little part of this :(

Comment: @RonBeyer no :( Libs have same structure of classes and they have only another implementation for different tasks. All methods are available. And I cant reference two dlls at the same type, because they have same structure :(

Comment: I understand that, is this a third party library? Seems like it would be easily done with one library that calls an internal XP function if running on XP, otherwise calls the vista function....

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, this is a third party library. That is MS library for testing drivers(WDK/HCK/HLK), and three this version, have same API, but one thing testing xp, next - vista,7,8, last - 10.